# java.io.NotSerializableException: android.system.keystore2.Authorization on an Android 12

Tags: java, android, serialization, cryptography

I have part of a code that generates a keypair and serializes it. It has been working since the release of android 12 (it means, it works on the lower versions of android), after that(on android 12) it raises this exception "java.io.NotSerializableException: android.system.keystore2.Authorization". This is my code:

```
public void generateKeyPairAndSerialize() throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                // *** Specified algorithm here
                // *** Specified: Purpose of key here
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
        kpg.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                "alias",
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                        KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .build());

        KeyPair kp = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(kp);
            out.flush();
            byte[] yourBytes = bos.toByteArray();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // ignore close exception
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anybody guide me to solve my problem.

Comment: Why aren't you using a `KeyStore`? Why are you using a home-grown serialization method instead? Do you understand that this is radically insecure?

Comment: Why insecure? the keypair stored in trusted executed environment but its handle stored in my app. any other app cannot access to my key because OS bans it

Comment: It's insecure because the file isn't password-protected. A `KeyStore` is. You should not reinvent the wheel. You should use the APIs provided for the purpose.

Comment: I made it password protected. one of shortcomings of keystore is they are extractable and hackers can steal them, but in this method privatekey cannot export from TEE.